# setTextColor at SharedPrefrences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have three buttons. Whenever I use ... to set text color for one of them, the color of all of them change at the same time, while I only want one of them to be changed. Do you have any solution? Please help. I am a beginner.

```
public class SecondAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnsave;
    SharedPreferences shrPref1;
    SharedPreferences shrPref2;
    SharedPreferences shrPref3;
    public static final String Mypref3="MyPref3", Mypref1="MyPref1", Mypref2="MyPref2"
            , btsob0= "ck0", btsob1= "ck1", btsob2= "ck2";

    Button btn0, btn1, btn2;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        btnsave = findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btn0 = findViewById(R.id.btnsob0);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btnsob1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnsob2);

        shrPref3 = getSharedPreferences(Mypref3, MODE_PRIVATE);
        shrPref1 = getSharedPreferences(Mypref1, MODE_PRIVATE);
        shrPref2 = getSharedPreferences(Mypref2, MODE_PRIVATE);

        btnsave.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            String sbtsob0 = btn1.getTextColors().toString();
            String sbtsob1 = btn1.getTextColors().toString();
            String sbtsob2 = btn2.getTextColors().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = shrPref3.edit();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = shrPref1.edit();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = shrPref2.edit();

            editor3.putString(btsob0, sbtsob0);
            editor1.putString(btsob1, sbtsob1);
            editor2.putString(btsob2, sbtsob2);
            editor3.apply();
            editor1.apply();
            editor2.apply();

        });

        if (shrPref3.contains(btsob0)) {
            btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        if (shrPref1.contains(btsob1)) {
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        if (shrPref2.contains(btsob2)) {
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        btn0.setOnClickListener(v -> btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN));
        btn1.setOnClickListener(v -> btn1.setTextColor(Color.CYAN));
        btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> btn2.setTextColor(Color.CYAN));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely the way that you're using `SharedPreferences.contains()`:

> ```
> if (shrPref3.contains(btsob0)) {
>     btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
> }
> if (shrPref1.contains(btsob1)) {
>     btn1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
> }
> if (shrPref2.contains(btsob2)) {
>     btn2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
> }
> ```

You've previously written values like this:

> ```
> editor3.putString(btsob0, sbtsob0);
> editor1.putString(btsob1, sbtsob1);
> editor2.putString(btsob2, sbtsob2);
> ```

This means that your `if` statements will always run, because you've always got *something* in your preferences with that key.

You probably want to be checking for some *value*, not just that the prefs store contains a given key:

```
if (shrPref1.getString(btsob1).equals("something here") {
    // your code here
}
```

---

Additionally, you have what looks like a typo here:

> ```
> String sbtsob0 = btn1.getTextColors().toString();
> String sbtsob1 = btn1.getTextColors().toString();
> ```

You probably don't want to be accessing `btn1` twice.

Comment: I did not fully understand. You can write a code like this for me that after clicking a button, the color of the text will change and it will be saved in the sharedprefrences without the other buttons changing text color.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you really need to reconsider your codes.

1. Using 3 `SharedPreferences` for different keys are useless. All keys are different so 1 `SharedPreference` is enough.
2. If you're using one `Activity` declerating variants as `public static` is a bad logic.
3. If you have 2 conditions, I suggest use `boolean` for storing values to `SharedPrederence` instead of `String`. You can easly handle your conditions with `boolean` value if you only have 2 conditions. If you have more conditions, use `int` value. For each `int` value you can define what you want to do just one time and you can use it for all `Buttons` without creating extra value.
4. You don't need to check if `SharedPreference` contains key. If you're using `SharedPreference` you should know that, while you're trying to get your values `get` method requires second argument (default value) for if that key doesn't exist.

I don't know if you want to also change `TextColors` when `btnsave` is clicked (If you don't, you can remove those lines). Whenever you click `btnsave` it will store `true` values to `SharedPreference` and it'll also change `TextColors`. (For a simple logic when `SharedPreference` values are `true`, `TextColors` will be those colors)

```
btnsave.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    shrPref.edit()
             .putBoolean(btsob0, true)
             .putBoolean(btsob1, true)
             .putBoolean(btsob2, true)
             .apply();
    btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    btn1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btn2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
});
```

Check for `SharedPreference` and if your values are stored, set desired colors, if not stored or `SharedPreference` doesn't exists set default values.

```
btn0.setTextColor(shrPref.getBoolean(btsob0, false) ? Color.CYAN : Color.CYAN);
btn1.setTextColor(shrPref.getBoolean(btsob1, false) ? Color.BLACK : Color.CYAN);
btn2.setTextColor(shrPref.getBoolean(btsob2, false) ? Color.RED : Color.CYAN);
```

Above codes are simple one line if else statement. It's same like below codes:

```
if (shrPref.getBoolean(btsob0, false)) {
    //If SharedPreference return true value
    btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
} else {
    //If SharedPreference return false value or if it doesn't exist
    btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
}
if (shrPref.getBoolean(btsob1, false)) {
    //If SharedPreference return true value
    btn1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
} else {
    //If SharedPreference return false value or if it doesn't exist
    btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
}
if (shrPref.getBoolean(btsob1, false)) {
    //If SharedPreference return true value
    btn2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    //If SharedPreference return false value or if it doesn't exist
    btn2.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
}
```

> I did not fully understand. You can write a code like this for me that
> after clicking a button, the color of the text will change and it will
> be saved in the sharedprefrences without the other buttons changing
> text color.

According to your comment, you want to change and save value when `Button` is clicked. But you only save when `btnsave` is clicked. You should also save when other `Button` is clicked.

```
btn0.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        shrPref.edit()
                 .putBoolean(btsob0, false)
                 .apply();
});
btn1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        btn1.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        shrPref.edit()
                 .putBoolean(btsob1, false)
                 .apply();
});
btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        btn2.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        shrPref.edit()
                 .putBoolean(btsob2, false)
                 .apply();
});
```

Full code:

```
public class SecondAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnsave, btn0, btn1, btn2;
    SharedPreferences shrPref;
    private final String Mypref = "MyPref", btsob0 = "ck0", btsob1 = "ck1", btsob2 = "ck2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnsave = findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btn0 = findViewById(R.id.btnsob0);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btnsob1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnsob2);
        shrPref = getSharedPreferences(MMypref, MODE_PRIVATE);

        btnsave.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            shrPref.edit()
                    .putBoolean(btsob0, true)
                    .putBoolean(btsob1, true)
                    .putBoolean(btsob2, true)
                    .apply();
            btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        });

        btn0.setTextColor(shrPref.getBoolean(btsob0, false) ? Color.CYAN : Color.CYAN);
        btn1.setTextColor(shrPref.getBoolean(btsob1, false) ? Color.BLACK : Color.CYAN);
        btn2.setTextColor(shrPref.getBoolean(btsob2, false) ? Color.RED : Color.CYAN);

        btn0.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            btn0.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            shrPref.edit()
                    .putBoolean(btsob0, false)
                    .apply();
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            shrPref.edit()
                    .putBoolean(btsob1, false)
                    .apply();
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            shrPref.edit()
                    .putBoolean(btsob2, false)
                    .apply();
        });
    }
}
```